# dojo equivalent of document.X

Tags: javascript, dojo

What will be the dojo equivalent code of following.?

```
var msgContainer = document.createElement('div');
msgContainer.id = 'alert';             // set id of div
msgContainer.setAttribute('role', 'alert');
msgContainer.className = 'contenthide' // set class name
msgContainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
document.body.appendChild(msgContainer);


var div = dojo.byId('alert');
while (div) {
 div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
 div = dojo.byId('alert');
}
```

Comment: you asked a *large* number of very elementary Dojo questions.  Perhaps you should really spend some time to read on Dojo's api documentation, as shown in @alex's link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var msgContainer = dojo.create("div", { 
                           id:"alert",
                           role:"alert",
                           "class":"contenthide",
                           innerText:msg }, dojo.body());
```

Please check on the Dojo Toolkit's documentation for more DOM functions.

Comment: thanks .Could you please let me know , how i can remove this div too, also can i attach a dojoAttachpoint to it?

Comment: Remove: dojo.destroy().  Attach points are used for dijit templates.  Do you mean to use dojo.connect() for connecting events?

Comment: @Stephen : I just added the js code which i use for removing div.I  wanted a dojo equivalent of above code

Comment: @jslearner, I am going to stop answering your questions from now on until you've read the Dojo api docs.

Comment: @Stephen: Sorry  , but i am a java developer and i have been assigned some dojo tasks which i am not much familiar with, i have a  shot deadline so i asked

Comment: @Stephen : I have posted one more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401082/validating-clearing-all-inputboxes-using-dojo. Looking fowrard to ur help

Comment: @jslearner, I don't think SO is here to save you time on reading docs. It is here for other to help you solve problems that you can't figure out yourself, not when you don't have the time to try solving it yourself.

Comment: @Stephen. Np. Thanks for all your previsions answers

Comment: @jslearner: if it helps, not everything has to be dojo.*  You can still use DOM / native browser methods, even in conjunction with other Dojo code. dojo.create is just shorthand for createElement+setAttribute+appendChild+etc.  But do read the docs.